# What is this square icon in Network Manager gui?

Tags: debian, networking, cinnamon

[image]

Within the last year I noticed that when I connect to my wifi network, the network manager gui looks normal but then after a few hours and more often at night it changes and I see two of the same network. One of them with the square and dot on top, and the other at the bottom with no dot or square. Sometimes they are surrounding other networks and sometimes not. Why does this happen? What does the square mean? I use the latest version of Debian and use the Cinnamon desktop environment and blackmate icon theme.

nmcli renders exactly the same with or without the square icon except  there is an extra "route4"

nmcli without square icon:

[image]

nmcli with square icon:

[image]

nmcli d wifi when the square icon is not present shows my network name twice with the BSSID the same except for the last two numbers and a few other differences.

[image]

When the square icon is showing nmcli d wifi outputs the same two previous networks and a third whose name is listed as "--" and which has the same bssid as the the other two but with two different last two numbers.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like my Network-Manager Gnome applet. What applet is that? Can you tell us its name? You can also try `nmcli` which is another front-end to Network-Manager: in a terminal, do `nmcli d wifi`. My guess: the left dot means "In Use" and the right square means "Absent / No signal" (admittedly it is contradictory but it may be a transient state... or just a bug)

Comment: The pic is the screen which comes up when you click the wifi icon on the taskbar. It shows in-range networks. I assumed it was part of the network manager gui. When the square icon comes up again I will try the terminal commands

Comment: Ok i edited the original post with the results of nmcli and nmcli d wifi